# ColdFusion sending encrypted form data via ajax

Tags: ajax, encryption, encoding, coldfusion, decoding

So I have a string that I need to encode in a hidden element in a form, and decode it after submission:

```
<input type="hidden" class="secret_number" value="#encrypt(0, 'foo')#">
```

So in the html, this looks god-awful, like

```
$&(A$4!v
```

Which causes errors with the URL, so I put it in URLEncodedFormat. So the final version looks like this: %25%28%25%5F%23WLT%20%0A, which is fine. If you decode and decrypt this it goes back to what it should be.

But after submission it looks like this:

```
%&#x28;%_#WLT
```

which errors on the decode because of the semi-colon.

Something of note is that on submission, this is running through an ajax call. Any ideas?

Comment: You are not stuck with the default uu encoding. You can specify the format as [hex or base64](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c2f.html). Also any reason you are using the legacy `cfmx_compat` algorithm? It is extremely weak and is only around for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get more URL friendly encoding

```
<input type="hidden" class="secret_number" value="#encrypt(string=0, key='foo', encoding='HEX')#">
```

I will also note that if you care about security in this situation then do not use the default CFMX_COMPAT algorithm.

```
<input type="hidden" class="secret_number" value="#encrypt(0, 'foo','AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding','HEX')#">
```

And don't hard code the key into the code either.

I am assuming you are doing this just to get proper encoded vs for actual security.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, here's my code: `<cfset encrypted_varb = encrypt(string=0, key='foo', algorithm='AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding', encoding='HEX')>` and I got a "Parameter validation error for the ENCRYPT function.

A built-in ColdFusion function cannot accept an assignment statement as a parameter, although it can accept expressions. For example, ENCRYPT(d=a*b) is not acceptable."

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using? I'll modify my code incase the version you are using does not support named arguments.

Comment: Of course, I am assuming you are replacing 'foo' with a proper 128-bit AES key.

Comment: No, I haven't replaced 'foo' with a 128-bit key, I've seen references to getGeneratedKey() or whatever, but how do I send that key through with the form data, without it being seen? Let's just assume a global variable is not a possibility. Also, I did not notice any modified code, where did you post it?

Comment: I modified the second code example above to not use named parameters. As for the key, you need to be able to store it somewhere on the server. You cannot send it to the client. Session scope? App Scope? Database? Text file? Somewhere on the server. Are you doing this for security?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18236/discussion-between-jason-dean-and-travisheeter)